# Spring: search resources in inner jar

Tags: java, spring, resources

I have a this war structure:
Some.war

-WEB-INF
--lib
---library.jar
----some.xsd
----some2.xsd

And i want to get all xsd files in library.jar, but spring don't want to search it.

```
ContextLoaderListener.getCurrentWebApplicationContext()
                     .getResources("classpath*:**/*.xsd")
```

result is empty. I also tried: `classpath:**/*.xsd`, `**/*.xsd`.

How i can get all xsd files in jar using "ant" template (**/*.xsd)?

Comment: I am not sure if classpath picks up files in a jar file. Someone might know better?

Comment: curious to know if library.jar!/some.xsd works?

Comment: @Amir a) yes it does b) "files" in a jar file are not "files", they are entries

Comment: Does it work if you specify the name of the `.xsd` rather than `*.xsd`? I understand you want to load multiple but this would test if the problem is in expanding `*.xsd` or finding the resources in the JAR.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer lies in the Spring docs:

> [**4.7.2.3 Other notes relating to wildcards**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-wildcards-in-path-other-stuff)
>
> Please note that "classpath*:" when
>   combined with Ant-style patterns will
>   only work reliably with at least one
>   root directory before the pattern
>   starts, unless the actual target files
>   reside in the file system. **This means
>   that a pattern like "classpath*:*.xml"
>   will not retrieve files from the root
>   of jar files but rather only from the
>   root of expanded directories.** This
>   originates from a limitation in the
>   JDK's `ClassLoader.getResources()`
>   method which only returns file system
>   locations for a passed-in empty string
>   (indicating potential roots to
>   search).

Comment: So it doesn't pick it up from jar files? Right? Or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: @Amir only if you do something like `classpath:config/**/*.xsd`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, sorry. "I will read references before ask" - i repeat it myself. Now i can use [it](http://icodesnip.com/snippet/groovy/search-entry-in-jar-files). Thanks.

Comment: @Alexey The Spring Reference is huge. Not knowing all of it by heart is not a reason to be ashamed :-)